# Advice on how to show a content for authorized/logged users

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, identity, asp.net-identity

Which of the following three authentication scripts is better and secure? I'm using the new asp.net Identity that comes with Visual Studio 2013 to authenticate users. Or has anyone a better option?

ASPX PAGE

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>

                STUFF FOR AUTHENTICATED USERS

            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

OR

```
  <% If (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) Then%>

     STUFF FOR AUTHENTICATED USERS

 <% End If%>
```

OR CODE BEHIND

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

        STUFF FOR AUTHENTICATED USERS


    End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally I go for the third way in the codebehind, but that is just my personal opion because I only develop in WebForms and not in MVC and therefore expect logic to be in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Session variable:

```
Sub PageLoad(default args here) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Session.IsNewSession Then
        Session("IsLoggedIn", False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Set `Session("IsLoggedIn") = True` when the user authenticates and check if that variable is true when needed.

Example:

```
Sub PageLoad etc
    If Session("IsLoggedIn") Then
        UserLabel.Visible = True
    Else
        UserLabel.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helped!

Rodit